# Dynamic path in move_uploaded_file is not working for me

Tags: php

I am a newbie to PHP. i want to create a newfolder and add the images to that folder while submitting the form. Newfolder in the name of the username is created as expected but the images are not inserted to the specific folder.

Attaching the php and form for review. It will be very helpful if someone help me

If i change the $username to the existing folder name in the move_uploaded_file, the images are getting inserted. It looks like i am missing something in mapping the path. Looking for the solution. Thanks.

```
    <?php include("header.php");
    error_reporting(0);

    if(isset($_POST['add_menu_submit']))
    {
    $gid=$_REQUEST['id']; 
    $qry1="select * from users";
    $exec1=mysql_query($qry1);
    $num1=mysql_num_rows($exec1);



$img1=$_FILES['image1']['name'];
$img2=$_FILES['image2']['name'];
$img3=$_FILES['image3']['name'];
$username=$_POST['username'];

 $cid=$_REQUEST['id']; 

$sqd= "insert into users(username,vanity,image1,image2,image3)values
('$username','$_POST[vanity]','$img1','$img2','$img3')";
$exe=mysql_query($sqd); 
$msg='Product Have been Added sucessfully!!!'; 
header("location:manage_collection.php");
if (!file_exists($username)) {
  mkdir($username, 0777, true);
}

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image1']['tmp_name'],$username/$_FILES['image1']['name']);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image2']['tmp_name'],$username/$_FILES['image2']['name']);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image3']['tmp_name'],$username/$_FILES['image3']['name']);

}




?>


<section id="main" class="column">
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <form action="add_collection.php" name="product" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <article class="module width_full">
        <?php echo $msg; ?>
            <header><h3>Add New Collection</h3></header>
                <div class="module_content">
                <div style="color:#FF0000"> <?php if(isset($error)) { echo $error; } ?> </div>
                        <fieldset>
                        <label>Pagename</label>
                        <input type="text" name="username" value="">
                        </fieldset>
                        <fieldset>
                        <label>Vanity</label>
                        <input type="text" name="vanity" value="">
                        </fieldset>

                        <fieldset>
                            <label>Image</label>
                            <input type="file" name="image1" id="image">
                        </fieldset>
                        <fieldset>
                            <label>Image</label>
                            <input type="file" name="image2" id="image">
                        </fieldset>
                        <fieldset>
                            <label>Image</label>
                            <input type="file" name="image3" id="image">
                        </fieldset>
                        <!--<fieldset>
                            <label>status</label>
                            <select name="status" id="status" size="1">
                            <option value="Active">Active</option>
                            <option value="Inactive">Inactive</option>
                            </select>
                        </fieldset>-->


            <footer>
                <div class="submit_link" style="float:inherit;" align="center">
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="alt_btn" name="add_menu_submit"> &nbsp;
                    <input type="reset" value="Reset" class="alt_btn1" >
                </div>
            </footer>

            </div>
        </article><!-- end of post new article -->
        </form>
    </section>


    <?php include("footer.php"); ?>
```

Comment: You should check the return value of `move_uploaded_file()`.

Comment: Also, passing `$_POST['username']` directly into `mkdir()` is asking for trouble.

Comment: Lastly, use prepared statements, because this script is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

please use one move_uploaded_file :)

```
$a=move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image1']['tmp_name'],$username/$_FILES['image1']['name']);
$b=move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image2']['tmp_name'],$username/$_FILES['image2']['name']);
$c=move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image3']['tmp_name'],$username/$_FILES['image3']['name']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides my earlier comments on the use of `move_uploaded_file()`, using `$_POST['username']` directly into `mkdir()` and SQL injection vulnerabilities:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image1']['tmp_name'], $username . '/' . basename($_FILES['image1']['name']));
```

The problem is that `$username/$_FILES['image1']['name']` is a division, not a string concatenation.

Secondly, you shouldn't use the full path that was given by the client; that's why I've added `basename()` to restrict paths like `'../../../../etc/php.ini'`.